# Updating javascript array data via input field

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, shopping-cart

I'm trying to create a shopping cart that builds an array to send to a server. The part I'm having trouble figuring out is allowing for the user to change the quantity via an input field that updates the 'quantity' value in the basketItems array.

I may be going about this wrong, but hopefully one of you geniuses could help me out.

```
var basketItems = [
    { itemName:"Item 1", price:1.00, quantity:0 },
    { itemName:"Item 2", price:2.00, quantity:0 },
    { itemName:"Item 3", price:3.00, quantity:0 }
];

var basketItemsTotal = 0.00;

function CalcBasketTotal() {
       for (i=0;i<basketItems.length;i++) {
           if (basketItems[i].quantity > 0) {
               basketItemsTotal = basketItems[i].price * basketItems[i].quantity;
           }
       }
}

function PopulateBasketItems() {
      for (i=0;i<basketItems.length;i++) { 
          basketTable.innerHTML += 
           '<tr><td>' + basketItems[i].itemName + '</td>' +
           '<td>$' + basketItems[i].price + '</td>' +
           '<td><input value="' + basketItems[i].quantity + '"></td>' +
           '<td>$' + basketItems[i].price * basketItems[i].quantity + '</td></tr>';
      }
}
```

BONUS: Eventually, I'm trying to make this script send the server this array along with the total, but first thing's first!

Answer (score 1):

your broblem is here :

```
function CalcBasketTotal() {
   for (i=0;i<basketItems.length;i++) {
       if (basketItems[i].quantity > 0) {
           basketItemsTotal = basketItems[i].price * basketItems[i].quantity;
       }
   }
 }
```

fix: (replace = by += to total)

```
function CalcBasketTotal() {
   for (i=0;i<basketItems.length;i++) {
       if (basketItems[i].quantity > 0) {
           basketItemsTotal += basketItems[i].price * basketItems[i].quantity;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Thanh. How should I call the CalcBasketTotal function? Onchange attribute? EventListener? I've explored those options but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: You can call whenever you change the array. If you want add onchange attribute, this only do with form input element.